# Apache2 Don't log bad requests for centain IPs in CustomLog

Tags: logging, module, apache2

### I'm trying to remove some IPs that are making noise over my little computer server

in the file  `/var/log/apache2/access.log` (custom log)

Here there are

```
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:12:38 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
194.54.83.206 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:13:21 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:14:59 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
194.54.83.206 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:15:22 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
64.62.197.62 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:15:48 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 281 "-" "-"
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:16:35 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
194.54.83.206 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:17:23 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:18:20 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:19:06 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
91.232.30.199 - - [11/Jul/2021:18:20:00 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1\n" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

So, if they don't make Bad Requests it's not difficult using mod_setenvif (SetEnvIf)

```
        SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^194\.54\.83\.102" dontlog=1
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined env=!dontlog
```

and they're hidden. In this way I've excluded also the logging of my localhost requests

But I don't have understand **if they makes Bad Requests (error 400) or some other errors like Not Found (error 404) how to hide them**

What I have to do?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/998182 maybe?

Comment: @f_puras https://serverfault.com/a/998182 The noise there is the same. They're doing bad requests. What you write works if they're not making Bad Requests. If they making Bad Request I see always them in my log file